# state on quantum statistics. 3 particles according to 3 distributions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

consider a system of three identical particles, A B ,and C.
Assume that each particle can be in one of three possible quantum states, 1,2 and 3.
For the following statistics listed below, enumerate the possible states of the system and calculate the probabilities that the state 1 has zero,one,two, and three particles.

a. Maxwell Boltzmann distribution
b. Bose-Einstein distribution
c. Fermi-dirac distribution

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE ! When asking a question, please explain what you know (so that one can know the level of the answer), what you have tried and where you have difficulties. You have to show some effort to find the answer.

Comment: well. sorry about that. but I have no clue this problem. so, please help me

Comment: What do you know about these statistics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the distributions are actually the macroscopical result from certain microsocopical assumptions. As your system is microscopic, I assume you refer to these assumptions, instead of the actual distributions. (The word distributions makes (in physics) only sense for a large number of particles.)

(If particles A is in state 1 and particle B in state 2, I'll write it in the following as A1B2 etc.)

These assumtions are:
a) Maxwell-Boltzman: Particles are **distinguishable**. (As your question sounds a lot like it's from a problem sheet, I guess you understand the meaning of this word in the context of statistical physics.)

For a a 2 particle system with two states each, the possible states are: A1B1, A1B2, A2B1, A2B2

b) Bose-Einstein: Particles are **indistinguishable** and an exchange of particles gives us a `+` in the wave function. This implies that the wave function needs to be **symmetric**.

For a a 2 particle system with two states each, the possible states are: A1B1, A1B2 + A2B1, A2B2
(I didn't put normailzation factors.)

c) Fermi-Dirac: Particles are **indistinguishable** and an exchange of particles gives us a `-` in the wave function. This implies that the wave function needs to be **anti-symmetric**.

For a a 2 particle system with two states each, the possible states are: A1B2 - A2B1
(I didn't put normailzation factors.)

This should help you to solve you excercise. I didn't fully answer the question on purpose, as I assume you would like to actually underrstand it yourself. I hope this answer brings you on the way. If you need more details, just write a comment with a precise question and I'll edit the answer.